# How can I make mutt show Date field of mail on the index screen?

Tags: mutt

I'd like to see the mail's date in the list that appears when I start `mutt`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set the `index_format` variable to include all manner of different details about each message. In particular, you probably want the `%d` format string, which inserts the date formatted according to the value of `date_format`, or one of the other date format strings, such as `%{fmt}`, `%[fmt]`, etc. As an example, here is my default `index_format` setting:

```
set 'index_format="%4C %Z %{%b %d} %-15.15L (%4l) %s"'
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#index-format) for more details on what you can configure, and what the extended date format strings represent.

---

config file

- ~/.muttrc or ~/.mutt/muttrc
  User configuration file.
- /etc/Muttrc
  System-wide configuration file.

```
#set date_format="%d %b %R"   # 06 May 07:55
set date_format="%F %T"       # 2021-05-06 09:20:03
set index_format="%4C %Z %D %-15.15L (%4l) %s"
```

Comment: Note that if you used `%d` (sender's timezone) or `%D` (your timezone) in index_format, don't enclose it in the curly brackets. For example, if in .muttrc, you have `set date_format="%d %b %R"`, you need to use `set index_format="%4C %Z %D %-15.15L (%4l) %s"` rather than `"%4C %Z %{%D} %-15.15L (%4l) %s"`. Otherwise you'll get the strftime interpretation of `%d` or `%D`. As the man page for strftime says: "Yecch."  (-:

Comment: Perhaps of some use, if you use NeoMutt (a more featureful mutt), conditional dates are a built in feature: https://neomutt.org/feature/cond-date